# How to get subset of string using Javascript/JQuery/JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, json

I want to get a subset of a string in Javascript. Currently, I only know how to store the entire string:

I have this as a JSON variable with a callback to foo:

```
foo({"results":[
"<div id=\"following\"><span><a href=\"http://twitter.com/barackobama\">Obama</a></span></div>"
]})
```

And this is my callback function:

```
function foo(o){
  var entireDiv = o.results[0];
}
```

**How do I store just the "< a href = ... > ... < / a>
" tag as a string in Javascript?**

Comment: why not just return the html fragment instead of json. Either that or return the data as json and use a templating plugin to produce the markup. Not sure why your trying to mangle the markup into a json string

Comment: it's given to me as json. i don't think i have control over the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, you can parse in a piece of HTML as the second argument.

So, to update your `foo` function:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

function foo(o)
{
    var JustTheLink = $j( 'a' , o.results[0] ).parent().html();
}
```

**Update:**
With multiple links to handle, you can do this:

```
function foo(o)
{
    $j('a',o.results[0]).each(handleSrc);
}

function handleSrc()
{
    console.log(this); // tag
    console.log($j(this).html()); // contents
}
```

Comment: working for me. If there are multiple links inside the html, how do I get the 2nd link, 3rd link, etc... ?

Comment: See my update for multiple links - doesn't seem a great way of doing things though... there has to be a better solution. :/

Comment: yea. since my input is relatively fixed, I know exactly how many links I have, so I figured out I should specify the links using a css selector. Works in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to find the anchor tag:

```
function foo(o){
  var entireDiv = o.results[0];
  var link = /<a.+?\/a>/.exec(entireDiv)[0];
}
```

Comment: Firebug says: "invalid regular expression flag a". Did you get it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = entireDiv.match(/<a[^>]*>.*<\/a>/);
```